# Какой род у слова "зубило"?

Tags: род, морфология

Что за сюрприз от словаря Ушакова, с каких пор «зубило» — мужского рода?

Comment: Мда.

Повторяю вопрос в лобовой формулировке: в чём может быть причина того, что словарь Ушакова считает «зубило» мужского рода, в то время как Даль, Брокгауз и Ефрон, Ожегов, Кузнецова, Ефремова, а также здравый смысл и чувство русского языка говорят о том, что оно — среднего.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Слово "зубило" среднего рода. По крайней мере, так говорит [википедия](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE)

Comment: Читайте по буквам: «сюрприз от словаря Ушакова».
Я прекрасно знаю, что среднего, так же как и остальные словари, но не Ушаков.

Comment: Если Вам не нравится ответ Kazuki , нужно более четко формулировать вопрос.

Comment: На пальцах?

Comment: Ну, Новикова вон, в своем словаре, в обиход прилагательное "брандвахтенный" ввела и никто, кроме меня, не жужжит :)

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, прилагательное вполне себе существовало и до упомянутой вами Новиковой.
Может вы, всё-таки, против употребления его в форме существительного возражаете?

Comment: Никогда оно (прилагательное) не существовало. Вот "брандвахта" существовала, это да.

Comment: Что же вы все так разволновались? Зубило - среднего рода. И всё!

Comment: А ЭТО?

http://www.google.com/search?hl=ru&tbo=p&tbm=bks&q=%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%85%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&num=100

Answer (score 1):

Benia, нужно учитывать, что словарь Ушакова создавался ещё на заре современной эпохи в лексикографии: издан в 1934–40, переиздан, насколько мне известно (я могу и ошибаться) лишь единожды, в 1947–48 гг. Будь этот словарь однотомником, потребность массового читателя в нём была бы значительно выше, а тогда он бы многократно переиздавался и от одного переиздания к другому количество опечаток в нём уменьшалось бы. А в том, что это именно опечатка, сомнений почти нет: ср., например, *долото,* которое в словаре верно отнесено к среднему роду. От себя добавлю, что находил в Ушакове написание *не при чём,* не соответствующее языковой норме *(ни при чём)*. Хотя здесь возможно и изменение нормы.
Кстати, какое издание словаря у вас?

Answer (score 0):

Завада: А что "это"? Набор безграмотной чуши - не более того. "Брандвахтенный пост", или брандвахтенный корабль - это "масло масляное", или "бикарбонад натрия двууглекислый", вот и все.
Как-то тут комментарии неудобно ставить...
Ну, начнем с того, что у Даля этого слова нет вообще (хотя сам он - морской офицер, между прочим). То, что написано в 1941-м году в "Морском словаре", для меня истиной в последней инстанции не является - тогда и "идти" через два "т" писалось, топикстартер примерно об этом же упоминает (зубило), да и образованность высших офицеров того времени под определенным вопросом. Ефремова же и Новикова тупо в данном случае переписывают встретившееся им (надеюсь, не в Интернете) слово, не понимая его точного значения. Если следовать их логике, то должны появится прилагательные "мателотный" (имеющий отношение к мателоту), "эсминцевый" (имеющий отношение к эсминцу) и т. д. и т. п.
P.S. За "бикарбонад" прошу прощения - профессиональное :)

Comment: «Морской словарь», «Современный толковый словарь русского языка Ефремовой» и прочие не согласны с вами: 
http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/sea/942/БРАНДВАХТЕННЫЙ 
http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/143288/Брандвахтенный

Что помешало вам создать свою тему, Тимур?

Comment: Тимур Казимиров, чушь — то, что Вы написали. Брандвахтенный — в словаре Ефремовой, в морском словаре, в словаре Даля и других словарях (см. Гугл-книги). Выучите слово ""бикарбонаТ".

Comment: Эсминец — всегда корабль, масло — всегда масляное, а брандвахта — не всегда корабль. 

"У Даля этого слова нет вообще". У Вас проблемы со зрением?

Даль пишет: "Брандвахта ж. немецк. военное сторожевое судно перед портом, гаванью. Брандвахтенный, к ней принадлежащий, относящийся."

Comment: Очки видимо разные, да?  
Это не Даль пишет (военное судно - нонсенс, чтобы вы знали на будущее, да и пришло слово не из немецкого, а из голландского), это Ушаков пишет, причем без упоминания о прилагательном. У Даля только "Брандахлыст" есть. Про термин "брандвахта"...? :))) Что еще брандвахтой может быть? Или вы остров Брандвахта имеете в виду? Ну назовите какой-нибудь остров Мателотом или Эсминцем - от этого прилагательное автоматом должно появиться? Если кто-то называет хибару на берегу брандвахтой, то она этим автоматически не становится. Поэтому брандвахта - всегда корабль!

Comment: Протрите очки. Статья "БРАНДАХЛЫСТ" из словаря Даля: "... Брандвахта ж. немецк. военное сторожевое судно перед портом, гаванью. Брандвахтенный, к ней принадлежащий, относящийся...". 

Задайте в Гугл-книгах "военное судно" (в кавычках — для точного поиска). Задайте в Гугле и в Гугл-книгах "брандвахтенный пост" (в кавычках — для точного поиска).   

Вся рота не в ногу, один Казимиров в ногу...

Comment: Гм. Любое судно, на котором поднимают военно-морской флаг, называется кораблем! Происхождение слова "брандвахта" голландское, а не немецкое, потому что в 18-м веке не было ни немецкого ВМФ, ни самой Германии как таковой.  
Ошибки накопляются? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Вероятная причина — описка Ушакова, связанная с родом слова "инструмент". А корректор прошляпил.

Comment: Да, вероятно.